# Unix pipe: find | ln -s

Tags: unix, find, pipe, symbolic-link, ln

I'm trying to symlink some php files using the following command:

```
find `pwd` -name "*.php" | ln -s * /home/frankv/www/bietroboter.de/symlinks
```

However, all the symlinks are broken because the little * does not reference the full path, only the file name itself. When I write them into a file using:

```
find `pwd` -name "*.php" > test.txt
```

It works. How can I pipe it correctly? Also, how can I tell it that I do not want any ".php" files that contain ".php~"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pipe takes the stdout from one process and connects it to the stdin of the next process; that doesn't make any sense for what you're trying to do (`ln` doesn't do anything with stdin).

You probably want something like this (untested):

```
find `pwd` -name "*.php" -execdir ln -s {} /home/frankv/www/bietroboter.de/symlinks \;
```

Comment: Thanks Oli. What would I do if, let's say, they are all written down in a file and I read them out with cat test.txt?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use xargs to execute commands from standard input:

`find` pwd `-name "*.php" | xargs ln -s -t /home/frankv/www/bietroboter.de/symlinks`